# Adding rows to DataTable from DataTable.Select() - column count not match?

Tags: c#, datatable, .net-4.5

I have code like this:

```
DataTable dtLevel1 = dtCategories.Clone();
DataTable dtLevel2 = dtCategories.Clone();

// i can workaround this with CopyToDataTable()
dtLevel1.Rows.Add(dtCategories.Select("id = 123")); // error


// but here similar situation, I cant use CopyToDataTable() method here
// because it will overwrite whole table in next loop run
foreach (DataRow dr in dtLevel1.Rows)
{
    dtLevel2.Rows.Add(dtCategories.Select("[pid] = " + dr["id"].ToString()));
}
```

On last line I'm getting error that says:

> Input array is longer than the number of columns in this table.

Why?

Edit/added later:

How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dtCategories.Select("id = 123")` returns an array of `DataRow` satisfying your select criteria, say for example 5 rows.

The overload of dtLevel1.Rows.Add which gets `object[]` actually gets an array of columns values in other words it expects **a row.** Your code messing up a Row with an array of rows.

Comment: I fixed your formatting. Ok, now I understand what is wrong. How to fix it?

Comment: @Kamil loop through the `dt.Categories.Select` to add each row to your `dtLevel1.Rows`

Comment: @KingKing I don't like that. There is no other way?

Comment: @Kamil is *KingKing* comment clear or you need a code snippet?

Comment: @KingKing That won't work, IIRC you can't add row of another table directly. You've to use `ImportRow`

Comment: @Kamil I don't understand what you don't like that, but if you want you can write an extension method to act exactly as what you want i.e Add(Rows[]).

Comment: All clear. Now I looked deeper into `Add` method and it looks like there is no "pretty" way and I need a loop. Thanks guys.

Comment: @Kamil Yes, there is another way using `LINQ to DataSet`, that's the method `CopyToDataTable`, you just need this: `dbLevel1 = dt.Categories.Select("Id=123").CopyToDataTable()`

Comment: @KingKing In that particular case I can use CopyToDataTable() method, but later I have similar situation when I need to insert many row arrays in loop. See question update.

Answer (score 1):

I would tackle this problem as follows:

```
    foreach (var row in dtCategories.Select("id = 123"))
    {
        dtLevel1.ImportRow(row);
    }
```

The problem is that you're trying to pass an array of rows to Add().  Add() expects a single row or an object array containing columns.  You should instead iterate over the returned results and use the ImportRow method to preserve any property settings.

Comment: My column definitions are copied from source table. Do I need `.ImportRow()` method?